# Send email from my ipad without receiving?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, email

Is this possible?  I went into settings and turned off "fetch new data", but if I send a message from an account, the durn thing still downloads all my mail in that account.  I don't want it to do that.

In other words, I want the email on my iPad to be write only.

Comment: Have you tried sending mail from within an app, Flipboard for example? Also, knowing why you don't want to download messages to your iPad might help. Is it because you are worried about space on your device? Is it because messages downloaded to your iPad then do not turn up elsewhere? What type of email account do you have - one of the free ones, a corporate one, your own domain?

Comment: I don't want to be bothered with it on the iPad.  It can wait for until I have a real computer.  The big red circle showing unread messages annoys me.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there’s an officially endorsed routine for this, but I’m sure it’s possible; it just depends on what sort of email account it is.

What follows is guesswork based upon poking around the Settings panel of my iPhone. I haven’t tried these methods, but these are what I think might work.

---

### iCloud

First you need to disable the default iCloud mail settings. On the iPhone, this is `Settings` > `iCloud` and toggle the switch next to `Mail` to `Off`.

Then we recreate the iCloud settings.

1. Navigate to `Settings` > `Mail, Contacts and Calendars`.
2. Select `Add Account…` in the Accounts list, and select the option at the bottom, `Other`.
3. Select `Add Mail Account` from the list of options.
4. Fill in all of your iCloud details, and tap `Next`.
5. On the next screen, under `Outgoing Mail Server`, fill in `Host Name` with `smtp.me.com`, and the User Name and Password as per your iCloud login. Under `Incoming Mail Server`, fill in gibberish in the fields.
6. Tap `Next`. You’ll get some warnings; just tap through them. For example, I have one that says

> This account may not be able to send or receive emails. Are you sure you want to save?
>   
>   But this is just what we want, so tap `Save`, and on the next screen, `Save` again.

In theory, your iCloud account should now be able to send mail, but not receive it. (However, it will probably fuss and grumble, and you’ll still have an inbox for the account, albeit empty.)

---

### Gmail or third-party mail server

Navigate to `Settings` > `Mail, Contacts and Calendars` > `Gmail` > `Account example@gmail.com`. Then, in the Gmail Account Information list, delete the Password. (In a third-party mail server, you’re looking for the Incoming Mail Server settings).

Hopefully, if the Outgoing Mail Server still has a correct username and password, you’ll still be able to send mail, but the iPad will fuss and grumble about receiving it.

---

I hope this is useful and works; or if not, gives you some ideas as to how to make it work.